# Maintaining the 'integrity' of tokens mapped with regexP-filter or wordforms in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

Taking the following as an example (nonsensical perhaps but to make a quick and understandable example):

```
regexp_filter = Photography => Videography
regexp_filter = graphy = > graphic
```

- A query for Photography will find itself and Videography and vice-versa.
- A query for Videographic will find both.
- A query for Photographic will find neither

Thus it appears the mapping had 'broken' Photography from further indexing other than itself (naturally) and the token it was mapped to, while the token it was mapped to (Videography) still obeys other regexp/wordform indexes.

Is there anyway to do the above (not including wordforms) that will map `Photography to Videography` and the suffix `graphy to graphic` and still allow Photography to obey the latter?

Answer (score 0):

Because the filters apply in sequence. The word 'Photographic' will NOT match the first filter, so not replaced. But the second filter WILL apply.

But Photography will match the first filter, and be replaced, AND will match the second too.

A couple of ways, eg, could just replace prefix seperately to the suffix

```
regexp_filter = Photograph => Videograph
regexp_filter = graphy = > graphic
```

Then the first filter applies, if its a /y or a /ic. The second rule already applies regardless if its photo or video.

Comment: Since mine did not work is the difference that you mapped *PhotoGRAPH' > VideoGRAPH vs PhotoGRAPHY vs VideoGRAPHY?

Comment: The point is my first filter, maps BOTH photography and photographic. regex filter doesnt automatically work on whole words. The filter is applied to the whole raw text.